# How to implement a large number of timers efficiently?

Tags: c++, timer, boost-asio

I'm writing a program in C++ that can potentially have hundreds of thousands of objects, each with an *expiry time*, that is they should be removed if inactive for a certain amount of time. Many of the objects become active very frequently and new objects are also created quite rapidly.

I have been hesitant as to what approach to use. I've been reading on Asio timers, but I'm not quite sure if they serve my needs well and, if they do, how. I have two approaches in mind:

1. I could make a dead-line timer for each object and reset it when the object performs something. This means that I will have hundreds of thousands of timers.
2. I could make a number of timer queues, for example, 30 timers for a 30-second expiry time. The first timer is for objects with 30 seconds of life-time remaining. If they are inactive for one second, they are moved to the timer queue for objects with 29 seconds of life-time remaining an so on. The objects in the last queue are deleted if inactive for one second. Any objects that becomes active goes back to the first queue.

The second approach sounds a lot more efficient, but is it really? If Asio can handle a very large number of timers efficiently, the second approach can be wasting a lot of effort on my part. Which way should I do it? Or is there a better way?

**EDIT:** I think I have to add that by efficiency I mean better CPU utilization. Memory usage is a secondary concern here.

Comment: I just edited my answer because I had misread your *Approach 1*.

Comment: I can't believe these answers.. The only correct answer is: Profile it!

Answer (score 3):

I would create a queue which keeps objects sorted according the remaining time to be expired. If expire time is expected to be frequent, I would use linked list, otherwise an array because it's faster to find something inside of the list (but if you keep references to next and previous object in the object itself instead of a node, it doesn't matter).

- Now you need only single timer for the object with lowest expire time.
- When this timer runs out, delete object at beginning of the queue and prepare timer for the next one.

Comment: I think the data structure you are looking for is a [priority_queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/).

Comment: Many of the objects become active quite frequently. It sounds to me that your approach leads to a lot of overhead, since every time an object becomes active, I have to move it in the queue. Although, I admit that might be exactly what Asio does when using many timers. In that case, perhaps I'd better use those.

Comment: @merlin2011 I see. Regrettably my STL knowledge is not complete, thanks for pointing that!

Comment: @Elektito I think it depends on implementation. If you would be working with nodes of the object in linked list, the moving shouldn't be so hard. Especially if you would keep references to nodes with some intervals (which would lead into almost binarny search)... (Btw. I don't know how Asio works.)

Comment: It is often the case that such timeouts have a common interval, eg. server timeouts on no comms from client.  Using a delta-queue approach is then fine because new entries will go at the end of the queue.

Comment: If a timeout needs to be reset, you could add a copy at the end of the queue and set a 'deleted' flag in the original entry so that the timer/thread/whatever ignores and deletes it it when it 'arrives'.  Saves shuffling the queue all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Make the plist of numbers and give the logic for timer.This is the most efficient way to implement for timer because it consume less memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first approach with the added twist that you *only delete objects when you try to perform an action and the deadline is expired*. It is much easier to implement is it is *lazy* in the sense that you do not evaluate a timer until you have to (meaning when you are trying to use the object).

If you think about efficiency, the work of deleting the object should be the same regardless of when you do it.

The memory to hold deadline times is going to be around 8 bytes per deadline, which is equal to the size of a pointer (required for approach 2) on a 64-bit system.

The only risk with approach 1 is that you might accumulate many more objects at once if you do not use them often. You can mitigate this by periodically sweeping through and deleting objects. As long as objects do not accumulate too quickly, you can sweep relatively infrequently.

Comment: Many of the objects do become active quite frequently, and new objects are also created very rapidly.

Comment: @Elektito, If it is sufficiently easy to implement this approach in your system, I would implement it, test it, and switch to something more sophisticated if you aren't deleting objects fast enough to keep up with your object creation.

Comment: @Elektito, If it turns out that you need active deletion, then Laethnes's answer is a good one.

Comment: May I ask what exactly you mean by "active deletion"?

Comment: @elektito, I just mean that there is a thread or function that is run periodically which wake up and delete stuff rather than only deleting on use of expired.

Comment: @elektito with active deletion there is no risk of an object staying around forever because the main program never touched it after expiration.

Answer (score 0):

If constantly creating new objects and deleting old ones, then consider using an object pool where you create a bunch of objects on program start up.  Increase the number of objects dynamically if you run out.  Increase the number of objects by a certain percentage (10% - 25%) instead of one at a time.  If an object is no longer needed, then return it to the object pool.  Consider using an algorithm to delete the objects in the object pool if memory is a concern.  It could delete 75% of the objects not being used every 5 or 10 minutes for example.

To implement this, consider using an available-object-pool list along with an in-use list.  Your object should have an initialization method that can be called to initialize an existing object.  The calling parameters should be quite similar to the constructor.  As for the container itself, you might want to experiment with using both a vector and a linked list and see which is faster.  If your app needs to search for objects, then a std::map or std::unordered_map would be a better choice.  An iterator could be used to go through the entire in-use list when the timer wakes up.

As for the timers, which do you think would be faster - having 500,000 timers wake up and do something once a second, or having just one timer that wakes up once a second to go through a list of 500,000 objects to see if an object should be returned to the object pool?  I think its pretty clear that using one timer is more efficient.  I would also be quite concerned if the 500,000 timers were to run on Windows either now or in the future.  I know some older windows OS would certainly crash.  How often should the timer wake up?  Try experimenting with values between 1 and 5 seconds.  It will be a trade off of memory consumption for longer wake up times .vs. CPU throttling for shorter wake up times.

Your 2nd approach sounds like what some garbage collectors do.  [Microsoft's .NET garbage collector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is organized into generations with short lived objects going into generation zero, longer lived objects in generation one, and longest lived objects going into generation two.

If doing multithreading, then consider using one object pool per thread.  Each object pool would have its own timer.